# How to count number and size of HTTP requests and responses in php + apache server apache2.2.25/php5

Tags: php, apache

Is there any log / configuration with which i get the number of requests and responses along with their size and processing time ? So that I can calculate the load for the purpose mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009684/android-tablet-accessing-data-from-lamp-server-on-network-what-should-be-the-c).
Version of apache used is apache is 2.2.25 and php5

Comment: Processing time will not be the same when you're under heavy load. There's really no substitute to a realistic load test using something like http://blitz.io/

Comment: you don't even need some freemium service like blitz.. If you're using Apache you can use a utility called ab (Apache Bench). It's free, always... and will give you an idea of how much your configuration will handle.